# drive api - write to shared folder not found

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I am using google drive api to write to a folder located in shared drive.
I have created a service account and service account is added to folder with permission as 'content manager'.

However, when I try to use the api to upload file, I keep getting an error stating 'folder not found'.
The same works fine when I try to create a folder onto my personal drive and add service account with 'editor' permission.

Can someone please help me if I missed something or that is as per design?

Below is sample code snippet:

google auth:

```
const driveauth = new google.auth.JWT(gSuiteUser, null,
   JSON.parse(gSuiteKey), [
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'
   ])
const drive = google.drive({
   version: 'v3',
   auth: driveauth
});
```

Below is the code for uploading on google drive:

```
const fileMetadata = {
    'name': 'Filename',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
    parents: [gSuiteFolder],
    convert: true
};
const media = {
    mimeType: 'text/csv',
    body: csvData
};
drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
}, (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(`Failure`);
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Success', file.data.id);
        callback(undefined, "done");
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you share the folder with the service account?

Comment: yep, folder is shared with service account :)

Comment: @DaImTo I am really confused that both folder has same configuration w.r.t. service account. The only difference is that one folder reside in shared drive with content manager role and another folder reside on personal drive with editor role

Comment: Could you add some code please.

Comment: I have updated the issue with sample code @DaImTo thanks!

Comment: @Anurajp  if you solved your issue consider adding your own answer to the question and accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that we need to send additional attribute 'supportsAllDrives' as true as shown below:

```
drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
supportsAllDrives: true,
    fields: 'id'
}, (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(`Failure`);
        callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Success', file.data.id);
        callback(undefined, "done");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something might be off in your deligation.

```
// loads credentials from .env file
require("dotenv").config();
import { google } from "googleapis";

function initializeDrive(version = "v3") {
  const client_email = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL;
  // add some necessary escaping so to avoid errors when parsing the private key.
  const private_key = process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
  // impersonate an account with rights to create team drives
  const emailToImpersonate = "some-user@acme-industries.com";
  const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    client_email,
    null, // undefined if you use TypeScript
    private_key,
    ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
    emailToImpersonate
  );
  return google.drive({
    version: version,
    auth: jwtClient
  });
}
```

Or maybe a bit more simple

```
const auth = new google.auth.JWT({      // JWT instead of GoogleAuth
    subject: "me@mycompany.com",        // include this property  
    keyFile: "service-account.json",
    scopes: [ ... ],
})
```

Comment: @DalmTo Turns out it was because I need to add an attribute 'supportsAllDrives' as true for team drives. Thanks for supporting me in debugging this :)